# Array single field update multiply

Tags: python

I generate a list and each element in the list is a list too. I do it using a function with a 'for' loop in it.
When I update the single value of the list it's updated in each sub-list instead.

I've noticed that when I create a list manually like:

`array = [['O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O']]`

all works as expected. 
But when I use my function which produces exactly the same output it fails.

```
def array_generation(size):
    array = []
    row = ['O'] * size
    for i in range(size):
        array.append(row)
    return array

myArray = array_generation(3)
myArray[0][0] = "S"
```

Actual Result: `[['S', 'O', 'O'], ['S', 'O', 'O'], ['S', 'O', 'O']]`

Expected Result: `[['S', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O']]`

Comment: This because lists are passed by reference. Each individual list in your super-list is actually the same list. You need to create copies of the lists instead and modify those. Simply put array.append(row.copy()) in your array_generation() function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a reference to the same list 3 times. You should make a copy of it instead using the `copy()` built-in method:

```
def array_generation(size):
    array = []
    row = ['O'] * size
    for i in range(size):
        array.append(row.copy())
    return array
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are generating your array, you append several times the same reference. So when you change the value of a pointer, you change every value.

Try that instead:

```
def array_generation(size):
    return [['O'] * size for _ in range(size)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are adding the same three lists, it carries the same reference, you could either use `copy` or create `Row` inside the loop like this:

```
def array_generation(size):
    DefArray = []
    for i in range(size):
        row = ['O'] * size
        DefArray.append(row)
    return DefArray
```